# How to add more property key value instead of overwriting in javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to create an archive system from google blogger api. I have the data as json of all posts from the blogger. Here is my code that I have tried.

```
var archive= {};
if("entry" in TotalFeed.feed) 
{
    var PostEntries=TotalFeed.feed.entry.length;
    for(var PostNum=0; PostNum<PostEntries ; PostNum++) 
    {
        var ThisPost = TotalFeed.feed.entry[PostNum];
        var key=ThisPost.published.$t.substring(0,4);
        var MonthNames=["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];

        var m=ThisPost.published.$t.substring(5,7);
        var NameOfMonth = MonthNames[parseInt(m)-1];

         archive[key] = {
            [NameOfMonth]: 1
         }
    }
}
console.log(archive);
```

The result of this code is

```
2011:{May: "1"},
2012:{January: "1"},
2013:{January: "1"}
```

There are many months in 2011 but you can see it only overwrite the last one. So I only get last month of the year from the loop. 
How can I get all the months listed?

Any idea or help is highly appreciated. 
Thank you.

**Edit: Key is not same, Here is a picture of the log**
[image]

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the `key` in the loop is always being the same, so when you do `archive[key] = {[NameOfMonth]: 1 }` it overwrites the previous data.

Comment: It's true that it's same for some cases but there are different months for sure.

Comment: can you create a codepen with the data? It'll be better to check the problem

Comment: Ok creating and thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a deeper object and you are also not checking if `archive[key]` already exists so you overwrite it if it does.

Try something like

```
// existing year object or create it
archive[key] = archive[key] || {};
//existing month array or create it
archive[key][NameOfMonth] = archive[key][NameOfMonth] || [];
// push item to appropriate month array
archive[key][NameOfMonth].push(ThisPost)
```

Or just to count year/month entries:

```
// existing year object or create it
archive[key] = archive[key] || {};
//existing month property or create it then increment count
archive[key][NameOfMonth] = (archive[key][NameOfMonth] || 0) +1;
```

Comment: Hi, one problem that I am trying to solve. My data is in descender order of the month like 2017 2016 but it always starts ascending order from 2011 2012.... 

Any idea? Thank you so much

Comment: Could map to an array. `var res = Object.keys(archive).sort((a-b)=>b-a).map(key=>({year:key, items: archive[key]})`...then do same mapping concept on months(items) to get them sorted